# Why is my site seal showing twice?

Tags: html

I had the site seal in the site footer and decided to add it to my shopping cart but when I added it in it started showing twice. I don't see the reason for it in my code but when I use Inspect Element in Chrome I see the html code twice. Please help. Thanks.

Code as written:

```
<div>
    <span id="siteseal"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://seal.godaddy.com/getSeal?sealID=KJGSDSjhc9CBNVZ8UcLh0kPNjNMidWC9qVfnCacP48aYykfDYSN">
       </script>
          <img style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand" src="https://seal.godaddy.com/images/3/en/siteseal_gd_3_h_l_m.gif" onclick="verifySeal();"> </span>
</div>
```

Code from Chrome:

```
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://seal.godaddy.com/getSeal?sealID=KJGSDSjhc9CBNVZ8UcLh0kPNjNMidWC9qVfnCacP48aYykfDYSN"></script>
         <img style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand" src="https://seal.godaddy.com/images/3/en/siteseal_gd_3_h_l_m.gif" onclick="verifySeal();">
         <img style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand" src="https://seal.godaddy.com/images/3/en/siteseal_gd_3_h_l_m.gif" onclick="verifySeal();">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The javascript gets the seal and displays it.  There is no need for both the script and the `img` tag.

Comment: It's sort of weird to me because this is the same code I used in the footer and it is only showing once there.

Comment: It looks like the godaddy site/script is running really slow right now.  Just use the script and you will have to wait a while for the img to load.

Comment: I was able to remove the second instance by removing the `img` tag and putting it back (not sure why or how that works but it did). It is still showing as two `img`'s in the code but only one seal is on the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the godaddy script gets and display another same image:

```
document.write('<img style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand" src="' + imageUrl + '" onclick="verifySeal();"/>');
```

So the best way to solve this is to remove the original img tag:

```
<div>
  <span id="siteseal">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://seal.godaddy.com/getSeal?sealID=KJGSDSjhc9CBNVZ8UcLh0kPNjNMidWC9qVfnCacP48aYykfDYSN">
    </script>
  </span>
</div>
```

or remove the godaddy script:

(no need to fetch the remote godaddy script so the page loads faster, but users can not verify the seal by clicking the img, cause we didn't load the godaddy script which provides the function `verifySeal()` )

```
<div>
  <span id="siteseal">
    <img style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand" src="https://seal.godaddy.com/images/3/en/siteseal_gd_3_h_l_m.gif" onclick="verifySeal();">
  </span>
</div>
```

It's the same.

Best Regards.